# I get “Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined” in a react-redux little test

Tags: react-redux

Please, can anybody help me with this test

I programmed a simple react-redux example, which has a list of products that the user can fill the cart with.
I created a reducer, like

```
const cartReducer = (prevState = storeInitialState, action)
```

where initialState is

```
export const storeInitialState = {
    forSale: GROCERY_ITEMS,
    cart: []
}
```

forSale are the products to sale, and cart are the product the user has in cart

By executing chrome developer tools with redux, I can see that the state has the products to sale correctly, but when trying to show them, I get “Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined”

In the component that shows the products in cart, I typed:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
       productsInCart: this.state.cart
    }
 }
 
 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        removeFromCart: (index) => dispatch(removeFromCartActn)
    }
 }
 
 export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GroceryCart)
```

Then, I show the products by iterating through the products in jsx:

```
{this.props.productsInCart.map((productInCart, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        <td>{productInCart.name}</td>
                                        <td>{productInCart.price}</td>...
```

Here is where I get the error “Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined”

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
       productsInCart: this.state.cart
    }
 }
```

It seems that the state is undefined, but why?

Thank you in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

In `mapStateToProps` you should just use `state.cart`, but not `this.state.cart`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
         productsInCart: state.cart,
    };
}
```

`this` inside `mapStateToProps` is pointing to a window object, so `this.state` is probably `undefined`.